# Why don't I find the Belgien eID-reader in the Software for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04

This picture is the proof it all was there in Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

It proves there were no less than 11 different software programs for the Belgian eID reader to be found under Ubuntu 14.04 and now after installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: none.

Comment: This [page](http://eid.belgium.be/nl/je_eid_gebruiken/de_eid-middleware_installeren/linux) allows you to install the necessary software. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install libacr38u libacr38ucontrol0 libacr38ucontrol-dev`

Go to http://eid.belgium.be/en/using_your_eid/installing_the_eid_software/linux

Install eid-archive.deb (This creates /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eid.list.ucf-dist on your computer.)

Remove your configuration file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eid.list

Rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eid.list.ucf-dist in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eid.list

In the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure eid-archive
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer
```

Open firefox and install in firefox the belgian eid add-on.

Firefox will complain that the middleware is not installed. Neglect this message. For me the eid-reader works with web-apps in firefox.
The eid-viewer does not work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same.

1. Go to http://eid.belgium.be/en/using_your_eid/installing_the_eid_software/linux
2. Download for Debian 7 "Wheezy", Debian 8 "Jessie", Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr", Ubuntu 16.04 "Xenial Xerus", Ubuntu 16.10 "Yakkety Yak", Linux Mint 17.3 "Rosa", Linux Mint 18.1 "Selena": `eid-archive.deb`

   - Middleware: `eid-mw.tar.gz`
   - Viewer: `eid-viewer.tar.gz`, or use the jar: `eid-viewer.jar`
3. After that in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i Downloads/eid-archive_2017.1_all.deb
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer
   ```